# Find a restricted domain so that the function is injective

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry

The sinus function is not injective when the domain is the whole $\mathbb{R}$.

To find a restricted domain where the function is injective, can we do that only using the graph or is there also an other way?

Such a resticted domain is for example $\left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right ]$. How can we find it?

Comment: For what it's worth, note that $\{0\}$ is such a restricted domain (works for any function with $0$ in its domain, in fact). Also, $\{\frac{3}{42}, \, \frac{42}{3}, \, 10^{100}\}$ is such a restricted domain. What you want is the largest such restricted domain that is an interval and contains the number $0.$ Oops, actually, even this doesn't quite pin down what you want! (Verification of last sentence left to the reader, where "largest" is by subset relation.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $f: A \to B$ be any function.

The restriction of $f$ to the empty set is injective.

---

Let $f: A \to B$ be any function defined on a nonempty set $A$.

If $a \in A$ then $f$ restricted to the singleton set $\{a\}$ is injective.

---

Let $f: A \to B$ be any function defined on a nonempty set $A$. Let the range of $f$ be denoted by $D$.

Using the axiom of choice, there exist a subset $C \subset A$ such that the restriction of $f$ to $C$ defines a bijective correspondence between $C$ and $D$.

---

The function $f(x) = sin(x)$ has range $[-1,+1]$ and the function $g(x) = \text{arcsin}(x)$ is a right inverse of $f$. The range of $g(x)$ is the interval

$\quad [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$

The function $f$ restricted to this set in injective.

If $h: [-1,+1] \to \Bbb R$ is any right inverse of $f$, then $f$ restricted to $h\big( [-1,+1] \big)$ will be injective.

Answer (score 0):

Find the interval on the graph is fine.

As an alternative we can consider the trigonometric circle and choose any angular interval such that any value for $\sin \theta $ is reached exactly one time.

The more natural choice is $\theta\in \left[-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2\right]$ but there are many other possibilities of course as for example

- $\theta\in \left[\frac \pi 2, 3\frac \pi 2\right]$
- $\theta\in \left[3\frac \pi 2, 5\frac \pi 2\right]$

and more in general all the intervals

$$[\theta_1,\theta_2]\subseteq  \left[-\frac \pi 2+k\pi, \frac \pi 2+k\pi\right]$$

works fine.

Comment: Using the graph, how do we know how big the interval has to be?

Comment: @MaryStar We need to take any piece of the graph which is increasing or decreasing since $f'(x)\ge 0$ or $f'(x)\le 0$ with $f'(x)=0$ not on an interval gurantees injectivity (it is a theorem).

Answer (score 0):

We know continuous, strictly increasing (decreasing) functions are always injective. Thus, we can just choose an interval where sin(x) is always increasing.